# In quantum process tomography for one and two qubit, why can we express the $\chi$ matrix in this form?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-process-tomography

I'm reading Nielsen and Chuang and I read quantum tomography process given by N&C (box 8.5), which provides an algorithm for determining $\chi$ in terms of block matrices and density matrices. And I'm pretty confused about the last two equation [image]

because the matrix $\beta $ seems not be necessary to calculate $\chi$ in this case just use the matrix $\Lambda$ and I don't know why we can express $\chi$ in this form?

The entire process to get $\beta$ matrix is detailed [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9610001.pdf)