# Prove $\beta=\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$, where $\Lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\X&-I\end{bmatrix}$ for single qubit tomography

Tags: quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, state-tomography, quantum-process-tomography

In the Section on single qubit quantum process tomography, [Box 8.5, Page 393, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), and in [Prescription for experimental determination of the dynamics of a quantum black box](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9610001.pdf), the procedure is formulated as

Choosing,
\begin{align}
\tilde{E}_0=I,\tilde{E}_1=X,\tilde{E}_2=-iY,\tilde{E}_3=Z\\
\end{align}

Suppose the input states are $|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|+\rangle=\dfrac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},|-\rangle=\dfrac{|0\rangle+i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ are prepared, and the four states

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(\rho_1)=\rho_1'=&\mathcal{E}(|0\rangle\langle 0|)\\
\mathcal{E}(\rho_4)=\rho_4'=&\mathcal{E}(|1\rangle\langle 1|)\\
\mathcal{E}(\rho_2)=\rho_2'=&\mathcal{E}(|+\rangle\langle +|)-i\mathcal{E}(|-\rangle\langle -|)-\dfrac{(1-i)}{2}(\rho_1'+\rho_4')\\
\mathcal{E}(\rho_3)=\rho_3'=&\mathcal{E}(|+\rangle\langle +|)+i\mathcal{E}(|-\rangle\langle -|)-\dfrac{(1+i)}{2}(\rho_1'+\rho_4')\\
\end{align}
are determined using quantum state tomography, where
\begin{align}
\rho_1=|0\rangle\langle 0|,\rho_2=|1\rangle\langle 0|=X\rho_1,\rho_3=|0\rangle\langle 1|=\rho_1X,\rho_4=|1\rangle\langle 1|=X\rho_1X
\end{align}

with $X=|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

From equation $\beta=\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$ we can determine $\beta$, and $\rho_j'=\mathcal{E}(\rho_j)$ determines $\vec{\lambda}$ using the equation $\mathcal{E}(\rho_j)=\sum_k\lambda_{jk}\rho_k$.

Then it went on to say that,

> Due to the particular choice of basis, and the Pauli matrix representation of $\tilde{E}_i$ , we may express the $\beta$ matrix as the Kronecker product $\beta=\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$, where $\Lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\X&-I\end{bmatrix}$, so that $\chi$ may be expressed conveniently as $\chi=\Lambda\begin{bmatrix}\rho_1'&\rho_2'\\\rho_3'&\rho_4'\end{bmatrix}\Lambda$ in terms of block matrices.

We have the equation $\tilde{E}_m\rho_j\tilde{E}_n^\dagger=\sum_k\beta_{jk}^{mn}\rho_k$

Is there any way to obtain the expression $\beta=\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$ without explicitly calculating each individual term?

Where does the tensor product comes into picture ?

Note: A similar question has been asked before [Quantum process tomography, for one and two qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27577/quantum-process-tomography-for-one-and-two-qubit), but did not attract any response.

---

**Quantum Process tomography**

Let a fixed set of operators $\tilde{E}_i$, which form a basis for
the set of operators on the state space so that $E_i=\sum_m e_{im}\tilde{E}_m$, then the quantum operation can be represented as,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(\rho)&=\sum_i E_i\rho E_i^\dagger \tag{8.150}\label{eq0}\\
&=\sum_{m,n}\tilde{E}_m\rho\tilde{E}^\dagger_n \chi_{mn} \tag{8.152}\label{eq2}\\
\end{align}
where $\chi_{mn}=\sum_i e_{im}e^*_{in}$ are the entries of a matrix that is positive hermitian since $\chi_{mn}^*=(\sum_i e_{im}e^*_{in})^*=\sum_i e_{in}e^*_{im}=\chi_{nm}$ and $\chi_{mm}=\sum_i e_{im}e^*_{im}=\sum_i |e_{im}|^2\geq 0$.

Let $\rho_j,1\leq j\leq d^2$ be a fixed, linearly independent basis for the space of $d\times d$ matrices,i.e., any $d\times d$ matrix can be written as a unique linear combination of the $\rho_j$ and it is possible to determine $E(\rho_j)$ by state tomography, for each $\rho_j$.

Each $E(\rho_j)$ may be expressed as a linear combination of the basis states, $\mathcal{E}(\rho_j)=\sum_k \lambda_{jk}\rho_k \tag{8.155}\label{eq5}$

And, since $\mathcal{E}(\rho_j)$ is known from the state tomography, $\lambda_{jk}$ can be determined by standard linear algebraic algorithms. we can also write $\tilde{E}_m\rho_j\tilde{E}_n^\dagger=\sum_k\beta_{jk}^{mn}\rho_k \tag{8.156}\label{eq6}$

where $\beta_{jk}^{mn}$ are complex numbers that can be determined by standard algorithms from linear algebra given the $\tilde{E}_m$ operators and the $\rho_j$ operators.

Combining both obtain,
\begin{align}
\sum_k\sum_{mn}\chi_{mn}\beta_{jk}^{mn}\rho_k&=\sum_{k}\lambda_{jk}\rho_k\tag{8.157}\label{eq7}\\
\implies \sum_{mn}\beta_{jk}^{mn}\chi_{mn}&=\lambda_{jk} \tag{8.158}\label{eq8}\\
\implies \beta\vec{\chi}&=\vec{\lambda} \tag{8.161}\label{eq61}
\end{align}
Let $\kappa$ be the generalized inverse such that $\beta\kappa\beta=\beta\Leftrightarrow \beta_{jk}^{mn}=\sum_{st,xy}\beta_{jk}^{st}\kappa_{st}^{xy}\beta_{xy}^{mn}$

We can prove that $\chi$ defined by $\chi_{mn}\equiv\sum_{jk}\kappa_{jk}^{mn}\lambda_{mn}\Leftrightarrow\vec{\chi}=\kappa\vec{\lambda}\tag{8.160}\label{eq60}$ satisfies the equation $\sum_{mn}\beta_{jk}^{mn}\chi_{mn}=\lambda_{jk}\Leftrightarrow\beta\vec{\chi}=\vec{\lambda}$

---

**Direct Approach**

Choosing,
\begin{align}
\tilde{E}_1=I,\tilde{E}_2=X,\tilde{E}_3=-iY,\tilde{E}_4=Z\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\rho_1=|0\rangle\langle 0|,\rho_2=|1\rangle\langle 0|=X\rho_1,\rho_3=|0\rangle\langle 1|=\rho_1X,\rho_4=|1\rangle\langle 1|=X\rho_1X
\end{align}

---

$\tilde{E}_m\rho_j\tilde{E}_n^\dagger=\sum_k\beta_{jk}^{mn}\rho_k$
$$
\tilde{E}_1\rho_1\tilde{E}_1^\dagger=\rho_1=|0\rangle\langle 0|=1\rho_1+0\rho_2+0\rho_3+0\rho_4\\
\implies \boxed{\beta_{11}^{11}=1,\beta_{12}^{11}=0,\beta_{13}^{11}=0,\beta_{14}^{11}=0}\\
\tilde{E}_1\rho_2\tilde{E}_1^\dagger=X\rho_1=|1\rangle\langle 0|=0\rho_1+1\rho_2+0\rho_3+0\rho_4\\
\boxed{\beta_{21}^{11}=0,\beta_{22}^{11}=1,\beta_{23}^{11}=0,\beta_{24}^{11}=0}\\
\tilde{E}_1\rho_3\tilde{E}_1^\dagger=\rho_1X=|0\rangle\langle 1|=0\rho_1+0\rho_2+1\rho_3+0\rho_4\\
\boxed{\beta_{31}^{11}=0,\beta_{32}^{11}=0,\beta_{33}^{11}=1,\beta_{34}^{11}=0}\\
\tilde{E}_1\rho_4\tilde{E}_1^\dagger=X\rho_1X=|1\rangle\langle 0|=0\rho_1+0\rho_2+0\rho_3+1\rho_4\\
\boxed{\beta_{41}^{11}=0,\beta_{42}^{11}=1,\beta_{43}^{11}=0,\beta_{44}^{11}=1}\\
$$
But this is quite cumbersome, and

$\Lambda\otimes\Lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\X&-I\end{bmatrix}\otimes\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\X&-I\end{bmatrix}\\
=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&-1&0\\1&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\otimes\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&-1&0\\1&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Looks like the calculation in my attempt do not match with the expression $\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$ !

---

***[Cross-posted on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4586046/173147)***

Comment: "We can determine $\beta, \lambda$". Sorry but what are $\beta$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: @JSdJ $\beta$ is a matrix with $(jk,mn)^{th}$ element is $\beta_{jk}^{mn}$, please have a look at "https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29111/why-is-chi-not-uniquely-determined-by-sum-mn-beta-jkmn-chi-mn-lam".

Comment: @JSdJ Or please have a look into the original publication, https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9610001.pdf

Comment: so if I understand: you have the channel in terms of its action on a set of states $\rho_i$ (spanning the relevant space of Hermitian ops), define the ops $\tilde E_i$ as some new operatorial basis (here the Pauli matrices as you write), define the coefficients $\beta$ as those in the decomposition of $\tilde E_m \rho_j \tilde E_n^\dagger$ in terms of the $\rho_i$, and define $\lambda$ as the coefficients in the expansion of each $\mathcal E(\rho_i)$ in terms of the $\rho_i$. You ask the relation between $\beta$ and $\lambda$. Is that correct?

Comment: @glS Thanks for responding. The relation between $\beta$ and $\vec{\lambda}$ are given by the relation $\beta\vec{\chi}=\vec{\lambda}$, so finding $\chi$ is the final objective. But, before that how do we even reach $\beta=\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$ where $\Lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\X&-I\end{bmatrix}$?